# How does on unmarshal to specific subclasses with XStream?

Tags: java, xstream

So, I have two classes, both are subclasses of another class and my XML can be either, both being named by the parent class and identified by the id attribute..

How does one make XStream unmarshal to the correct class?

Code:

```
@XStreamAlias("Extension")
public class Extension {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("Id")
    private String id;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("Required")
    private boolean required;

    /* getters and setters */

}

@XStreamAlias("Extension")
public class ULExtension extends Extension {

    @XStreamAlias("ULData")
    private ULData ULData;
    /* getter and setter */
}

@XStreamAlias("Extension")
public class XTExtension extends Extension {

    @XStreamAlias("ExtConverter")
    private ExtConverter extConverter;
    /* getter and setter */
}
```

The XML coming in looks as such

```
<Extension Id="UL" Required="false"><ULData><stuffAndThings/></ULData></Extension>
```

or

```
<Extension Id="XT" Required="false"><ExtConverter><otherStuffAndThings/></ExtConverter></Extension>
```